# Drupal Module for Interacting with Second Database?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

Our Drupal site is to leverage data from a second MySQL database. The conneciton is already in place in settings.php

I'm wondering now if there is a module I can use to interact with it (select, update, etc). Or at least what's the best practice working with SQL queries - GUI with a module, or code?

One goal is to display the results on screen, and allow the User to filter rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

in settings.php:

```
$databases = array();

$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'newdatabase',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' => 'root',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'prefix' => '',
  'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
);


 $databases['legacy']['default'] = array(
   'driver' => 'mysql',
   'database' => 'olddatabase',
   'username' => 'root',
   'password' => 'root',
   'host' => 'localhost',
   'prefix' => '',
   'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
 );
```

then in yor code, you can switch with db_set_active() function.  To switch back leave db_set_active first parameter empty.

for example, see below:

```
db_set_active('legacy');
```

then

db_set_active(`enter code here`);

which will switch back to main database.

In the example below, I use a for loop and an array to grab a series of data from old database and new database.

```
      $outputArray = array();


  $data = array(
    'article' => array(
        'number of articles' => array(
          'legacy' => "select count(*) from node WHERE type = 'article';",
          'new' => "select count(*) from node WHERE type = 'article';",
        ),
        'field_byline' => array(
          'default_style' => TRUE,
          ),
        'field_images' => array(
          'fid_style' => TRUE,
         ),
        'field_subtitle' => array(
          'default_style' => TRUE,
          ),
        'field_blurb' => array(
          'default_style' => TRUE,
          ),
        'field_teaser_image' => array(
          'fid_style' => TRUE,
         ),
         'field_rotator_image' => array(
          'fid_style' => TRUE,
         ),
        'field_photo_credit' => array(
          'default_style' => TRUE,
          ),
        'field_videos' => array(
          'fid_style' => TRUE,
         ),
        'field_issue_id' => array(
          'default_style' => TRUE,
          ),
         'field_aol_player' => array(
           'default_style' => TRUE,
         ),
         'field_brightcove_id' => array(
           'default_style' => TRUE,
         ),
         'field_related_articles' => array(
           'legacy' => "select count(DISTINCT(CONCAT(nid, field_related_articles_nid))) from content_field_related_articles WHERE field_related_articles_nid IS NOT NULL;",
          'new' => "select count(*) from field_data_field_related_articles WHERE field_related_articles_target_id IS NOT NULL;",
         ),
    ),
  );


  foreach($data as $type => $type_data) {
    foreach($type_data as $field => $field_data) {

      if(isset($field_data['default_style']) && $field_data['default_style'] == TRUE) {
        $field_data['legacy'] = "select count(DISTINCT(nid)) from content_" . $field . " WHERE " . $field . "_value IS NOT NULL;";
         $field_data['new'] =  "select count(*) from field_data_" . $field . " WHERE " . $field . "_value IS NOT NULL;";
      }

      else if(isset($field_data['fid_style']) && $field_data['fid_style'] == TRUE) {
        $field_data['legacy'] = "select count(DISTINCT(nid)) from content_" . $field . " WHERE " . $field . "_fid IS NOT NULL;";
         $field_data['new'] =  "select count(*) from field_data_" . $field . " WHERE " . $field . "_fid IS NOT NULL;";
      }

      else if(isset($field_data['nid_style']) && $field_data['nid_style'] == TRUE) {
        $field_data['legacy'] = "select count(*) from content_" . $field . " WHERE " . $field . "_nid IS NOT NULL ;";

         $field_data['new'] =  "select count(*) from field_data_" . $field . " WHERE " . $field . "_target_id IS NOT NULL;";

      }      



      db_set_active('legacy');
      $count = (int) db_query($field_data['legacy'])->fetchField();

      db_set_active();
      $count_new =  (int) db_query($field_data['new'])->fetchField();


      $outputArray[$type][$field]['legacy'] = $count ;
      $outputArray[$type][$field]['new'] = $count_new;     
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For everone else's reference, if you don't already have the second database in your settings.php, you can do this:

```
global $databases;

$seconddb = $databases['default']['default'];
$seconddb['database'] = 'seconddb';

Database::addConnectionInfo('seconddb', 'default', $seconddb);
db_set_active('seconddb');

// ...

db_set_active('default');
```